# Get value where class equals active

Tags: javascript, jquery

**RESOLVED**
It was determined that the issue is only on the platform we use thus all answers provided could be probably be right.

Added another question regarding the same problem at [Insert a var into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181941/java-insert-a-var-into-a-string)

I'm struggling to find a solution to a search query we have on our website. It consists of a tabbed selection where certain specifics then can be selected. When two or more tabs have been selected before selecting the specifics, all tab selections are included in the search results. We want to only show results for the last selected tab.

Part of our HTML:

```
<div class="searchTabContainer col-xs-7" id="searchTabContainer">
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab1" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(1);">Model 1</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab2" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(2);">Model 2</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab3" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(3);">Model 3</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab4" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(4);">Model 4</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab5" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(5);">Model 5</div>
</div>
```

When a tab is selected it adds it to class active:

```
    function setActiveTab(x) {
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            $("#searchTab" + i).removeClass('active');
            searchURL = "";
            if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('specials') > -1) {
                collectionURL = "/collections/";
            }
            else {
                collectionURL = "/collections/";
            }
        }
        $(".Filter").find("input[type=text], textarea, select").val("");
        $("#searchTab" + x).addClass('active');
        if (x == 0){
                searchBrand = ""
        }
        else if (x == 1) {
                searchBrand = "model1"
        }
        else if (x == 2) {
                searchBrand = "model2"
        }
        else if (x == 3) {
                searchBrand = "model3"
        }
        else if (x == 4) {
                searchBrand = "model4"
        }
        else if (x == 5) {
                searchBrand = "model5"
        }
```

Then it includes the search part which is:

```
//edit line//
     var searchBran = searchBrand;
//end edit line//

$('.homePageProducts a').each(function(){
  var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('/search?q=','/search?q='+searchBran+'%20');
  $(this).attr('href', newurl);
});

    goToByScroll();

    return false;
}
```

NOTE: The edit line is where most of my testing happens.

As said, this script as said, show results for each tab click before search selection.

At the edit line I have tried multiple scripts as found on Stack Overflow and over places on Internet. Some of these (quite mixed up):

```
//      $("#searchTab" + x).find(".active").each(function(){
//      $('.active').each(function() { 
//      $(".searchTab.active").each(function(){
//          var searchBran = searchBrand;
//      });
//var searchBran = $('.searchTab').filter('.active');
//var searchBran = $('.searchTab.active');
```

With this script the URL result is:

```
https://www.sactrucks.co.za/search?q=model1%20model2%20selection5&type=product
```

The URL result should be:

```
https://www.sactrucks.co.za/search?q=model2%20selection5&type=product
```

Any assistance to resolve this search issue will be greatly appreciated.

Homepage links for reference:

```html
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=engine%20oil%20sump&type=product">Oil Sump</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=engine%20alternator&type=product">Alternator</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=engine%20intake%20and%20exhaust%20manifold&type=product">Intake & Exhaust Manifold</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Question is somewhat unclear. What is the final `href` of `$('.homePageProducts a')`  you want, say when you click model1, model2 model3 in sequence

Comment: Also, can u combine all these snippets into a single working one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `collectionURL = "/collections/";` without the if?

Comment: The post was edited to show the URL current and the ideal. The full script is    has quite a bit unneeded information, will try to cut down to only the needed info for this request and ad to post

Comment: @Hackerman, that section seems to be unneeded currently as there is no specials for this page as yet

Comment: @JanBal can multiple tabs be active at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand with your expected vs actual URL result, the problem should be in your `replace` method. Try with modified `regex`:

```
$(this).attr('href').replace(/\/search\?q=[^\&]*/, '/search?q=' + searchBran + '%20');
```

`[^\&]*` : it will look for all characters expect `&` (next set of query params)

Given that only one tab is active at a time (evident from code) and assuming that the second code block is also inside `setActiveTab` function block, you are only replacing the string `/search?q=`. This will be modifying the `href` as

```
/search?q=model1%20
```

Now clicking on model 2, will replace only the `/search?q=` portion, modifying to:

```
/search?q=model2%20model1%20
```

```js
function setActiveTab(x) {
  /*for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $("#searchTab" + i).removeClass('active');
    searchURL = "";
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('specials') > -1) {
      collectionURL = "/collections/";
    } else {
      collectionURL = "/collections/";
    }
  }*/
  // refactoring the above loop with below line as it is not affecting the OP question
  $(".searchTab").removeClass("active");
  $(".Filter").find("input[type=text], textarea, select").val("");
  $("#searchTab" + x).addClass('active');
  if (x == 0) {
    searchBrand = ""
  } else if (x == 1) {
    searchBrand = "model1"
  } else if (x == 2) {
    searchBrand = "model2"
  } else if (x == 3) {
    searchBrand = "model3"
  } else if (x == 4) {
    searchBrand = "model4"
  } else if (x == 5) {
    searchBrand = "model5"
  } //edit line//
  var searchBran = searchBrand;
  //end edit line//


  $('.homePageProducts a').each(function() {
    var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\/search\?q=[^\&]*/, '/search?q=' + searchBran + '%20');

    // only for display
    $("#newUrl").prepend("<p>" + newurl + "</p>");

    $(this).attr('href', newurl);
  });

  // goToByScroll();

  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchTabContainer col-xs-7" id="searchTabContainer">
  <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab1" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(1);">Model 1</div>
  <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab2" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(2);">Model 2</div>
  <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab3" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(3);">Model 3</div>
  <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab4" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(4);">Model 4</div>
  <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab5" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(5);">Model 5</div>
</div>

<div class="homePageProducts">
  <a href="/link1/search?q=null&abc=123&xyz=456">Link 1</a>
  <a href="/link2/search?q=null&abc=222">Link 2</a>
</div>


<div id="newUrl"></div>
```

Comment: your answer sure did help, but the regex did then create new problems which due to my lack of knowledge can't yet correct.
One specifics href:
`<a href="/search?q=body%20inner&type=product">Body Inner</a>`
give:
`https://www.example.com/search?q=model1%20&type=product`
while another specif href:
`<a href="/search?q=gearbox%20&%20drive%20hydra%20part&type=product">Hydra Part</a>'
give:
`https://www.example.com/search?q=scania%20&%20drive%20hydra%20part&type=product`

Comment: ignore my last comment, should've just stop being lazy sooner, adjusted to `(/\/search\?q=/, '/search?q=' + searchBrand + '%20');` which seems to resolved the issue. More testing will be done to confirm.

Comment: your answer is surely a step in the right direction but still provide some other errors I cant yet resolve. I will read into the regex as that surely will provide the solution when correct format is used

Comment: cool, that's why i had put a disclaimer at the start of the answer, it was based on certain assumptions. Give Regex a read and you still need help refine your question for the actual problem