# Insert a var into a string

Tags: jquery, html

**RESOLVED**
It was determined that the issue is only on the platform we use thus all answers provided could be probably be right.

*This question is based on a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166271/get-value-where-class-equals-active)*

---

This code of tab selections:

```
<div class="searchTabContainer col-xs-7" id="searchTabContainer">
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab1" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(1);">MAKE 1</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab2" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(2);">MAKE 2</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab3" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(3);">MAKE 3</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab4" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(4);">MAKE 4</div>
    <div class="searchTab" id="searchTab5" onclick="javascript:return setActiveTab(5);">MAKE 5</div>
</div>
```

Assign classes and create a new var:

```
$(".searchTab").removeClass("active");
    $(".Filter").find("input[type=text], textarea, select").val("");
    $("#searchTab" + x).addClass('active');
    if (x == 0){
            searchBrand = ""
    }
    else if (x == 1) {
            searchBrand = "make1"
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
            searchBrand = "make2"
    }
    else if (x == 3) {
            searchBrand = "make3"
    }
    else if (x == 4) {
            searchBrand = "make4"
    }
    else if (x == 5) {
            searchBrand = "make5"
    }
```

Combined with a homepage link:

```
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=body%20mirrors&type=product">Mirrors</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=body%20air&type=product">Air</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/search?q=body%20hydraulics&type=product">Hydraulics</a>
</p>
```

Gets edited to a new url for searching:

```
$('.homePageProducts a').each(function(){
  var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('/search?q=', '/search?q=' + searchBrand + '%20');
  $(this).attr('href', newurl);
});
```

This process works good but when to makes is click subsequently before the final line, both appear in the URL like:

```
https://www.example.com/search?q=make3%20make5%20%20body%20air&type=product
```

The default homepage search result without make results to:

```
https://www.example.com/search?q=%20body%20air&type=product
```

---

The question before provided a possible solution to regex but it would also appear that of instead of replacing the homepage url, only insert the searchBrand into the default search url to achieve:

```
https://www.example.com/search?q=make3%20body%20air&type=product
```

This might resolve the multiple makes issue. I have tried:

```
var newurl = $(this).attr('href').insert(10, searchBrand + '%20');
```

and a few variations of this without success of getting the `searchBrand` inserted into `newurl`. 
How can I achieve this result?

Comment: @Stultuske And need to edit the title too.

Comment: So many code snippets. I dont know what to check. :)

Comment: and some snippets are just links..

Comment: sorry for the many snippets, justy tried to make it more easy to process go through it

Comment: There is no need to insert snippets if the code is not runnable.. Just mark the code as code instead of inserting snippets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying simple JavaScript could be the trick. Using a new:

```
var url = "Your first part of the link goes here" + searchBrand + "end of your link";
```

Then just call the `var` when you need it. Hope that helps!!

Comment: This one don't seem to help unless I have it wrong. I need to add searchBrand into `href="/search?q=body%20air&type=product"`between **q=** and **body** when selected to achieve `https://www.example.com/search?q=SEARCHBRAND%20body%20air&type=product`